# Запретить пересоздание Activity при повороте экрана

Tags: java, android

Есть компонент WebView . И при повороте экрана пользователь оказывается на начальной странице сайта. 
Как можно исправить это?
Пытался в манифест добавить `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` - не помогло. 
Вот код компонента:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<WebView android:id="@+id/wv" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>
```

код Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static final String PREFS_NAME = null;
protected static String LASTURL = null;
private WebView wv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);




WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
webSettings.setSavePassword(true);
webSettings.setSaveFormData(true);
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
final boolean imgOn = settings.getBoolean("IMGMODE", false);
webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(imgOn);

final Activity activity = this;

wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
  public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
  {
    activity.setTitle(" "+LASTURL);
    activity.setProgress(progress * 100);
    if(progress == 100)
      activity.setTitle(" "+LASTURL);
  }
});
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
  public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + description+ " " + failingUrl, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }

  @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
  {
    if (url.indexOf("kaztest")<=0) {

      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
      startActivity(intent);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  public void onPageStarted (WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
    LASTURL = url;
    view.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
  }

  public void onPageFinished (WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
        "hide('sidebar');"+
        "var panel = document.getElementById('search');"+
        "panel.style['width'] = '55px';"+
        "function hide(id){if (document.getElementById(id)){document.getElementById(id).style['display'] = 'none';}}"+              //"function hideByClass(c){var e=document.getElementsByClassName(c);for(var i=0;i<e.length;i++){e[i].style['display'] = 'none';}}"+
        "})()");
    if (imgOn) view.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
  }
});

wv.loadUrl("http://kaztest.ru/?version=app");
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && wv.canGoBack()) {
  wv.goBack();
  return true;
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}



private void saveSettings(Boolean val)
{
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putBoolean("IMGMODE", val);
editor.commit();
}

}
```

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

**Запрет автоматического пересоздания Activity**

В `AndroidManifest.xml` дописать в раздел activity

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

Но этот метод не рекомендуемый, так как в сложных приложениях придется самостоятельно обновлять данные внутри программы.

**Чтобы запретить поворот экрана**

В раздел activity вписать

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

или

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

**Сохранение данных Activity при повороте экрана**

По этой теме [тут](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/133-urok-70-onsaveinstancestate-sohranenie-dannyh-activity-pri-povorote-ekrana) есть туториал.

Comment: в эмуляторе `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` действует. на устройстве - нет

Comment: @Денис а на разных эмуляторах все нормально работает, как хотел? Может тогда проблема в устройстве? Если есть возможность, то попробуй на другом устройстве запустить.

Comment: На эмуляторе Android 2.3.3, на устройстве Android 4.2.1 Устройство полностью исправно.

Comment: А на эмуляторе с Android 4.2.x или выше работает?